# error fetching all radio button values in array while updating the attendance in php

Tags: php, html

I am working on attendance system. While on updating the attendance first I get all the results according to the class and date in the table and along with every result of the row there are two radio buttons where one is checked if the student is present and the other radio button is unchecked.

This is the result I get  when I select class and date - you can see in the picture:

[image: Pageof update]

After that if I have to update the attendance of particular student I press the radio button and select "present" or "absent" to update. But when I submit the code I get the update result of only first row. And the other rows are missing from the array.

This is the code of the front-end where I set two conditiond on the radio buttons - if value is "present" then the radio button with the value "present" is checked, or else if the value is "absent" then the radio button with the value "absent" is checked.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulted)) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['userid'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['grade'] ?></td>

                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="attendance_id[]"/>

                    <?php
                    if ($row['attendance'] == 'present') {
                        ?>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $count ?>]" value="present" <?php echo "checked" ?>/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $count ?>]" value="absent"/></td>
                    <?php } else if ($row['attendance'] == 'absent') {

                        ?>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $count ?>]" value="present"/></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="attendance_status[<?php echo $count ?>]"
                                   value="absent" <?php echo "checked" ?> /></td>

                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $count++;
            } ?>
```

This is the backened code where I am getting the result:

```
if (isset($_POST['updateAtt']))
{
        foreach ($_POST['attendance_status'] as $id => $attendance_status) {
            $id = $_POST['attendance_id'][$id];
            echo $id . " " . $attendance_status . " ". "<br>";
        }
```

Comment: Why `attendance_status[<?php echo $count ?>]`? Why not just `attendance_status[]`? Try it like that and see if it helps.

Comment: no its not working if i got it removed only last row of record radio button got checked

Comment: Strange. Check your network tool in the browser and look at the payload of the request when you submit the form, and see if the data being sent matches your expectation. Paste the payload data here (or link to a screenshot) if you're unsure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue:

```
if (isset($_POST['updateAtt']))
{
        foreach ($_POST['attendance_status'] as $ids => $attendance_status) {
            $ids = $_POST['attendance_id'][$id];
            echo $ids . " " . $attendance_status . " ". "<br>";
        }
```

Actually, I declared the id variable in foreach and then when I am getting the value of attendance_id I used it again. That is why it had only one value.